# Android Xamarin Forms App maintain WiFi connection without internet

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Our IoT App created in Xamarin Forms for Android is working well when connecting to the IoT device Access Point over WiFi. But we are getting random issues where some users are experiencing their smart device disconnecting from the access point because it has no internet. There does not seem to be any commonality I can find here many users with the same devices have different experience!

I have googled this at it appears a common issue - set the network to non adaptive etc... has no affect!

Is there a way i can force the device programmatically to stay on a non internet available WiFi network until i disconnect?

Comment: This is the design by Android. You can check this answer to check [How to programmatically connect to Wifi with no internet Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62300642/how-to-programmatically-connect-to-wifi-with-no-internet-android-xamarin).